# Is there a way to tell android force stop activity which going to background without removing it from activity stack?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have some floating bugs in my app, which unable to reproduce clearly. I suspect them from inproper work of my SaveInstanceState|restoreInstanceState mechanism, so I need to check case, when activity is being stopped when goes to background, and recreating after I press back button from spawned activity. Is there a way to force android stop and destroy activity which went to background? It should remain on activity stack, so I cannot just finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable the developer option "don't keep activities" (or whatever its called). This won't remove the activity from the stack, but will actually call `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` whenever the user leaves the activity and opens another. When the user presses BACK, Android will create a new instance of the activity, and call `onCreate()` and onRestoreInstanceState()` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024803/killing-android-application-on-pause) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131585/how-to-destroy-an-activity-in-android) questions. Override onPause() method and call method finish() in it.

Comment: calling `finish()` will remove activity from history stack

Comment: Your logic is a bit strange: on one side you want to force close and destroy the activity and on the other side you want have it in history stack.

Comment: Here is a quote about activities states from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

'When the user leaves a task, current activity is stopped and its task goes into the background. If the user resumes the task, the task comes to the foreground and resumes the activity at the top of the stack. 

If the user presses the Back button, activity is **popped from the stack and destroyed**. The previous activity in the stack is resumed. **When an activity is destroyed, the system does not retain the activity's state.**'

Comment: So if you want to save activity state and have it in stack, you shouldn't override the onPause() method. But if you want to force close the activity, it'll be removed from stack.

Comment: Well, never mind. In case android has low memory, activity may be destroyed while on stack, and when user press back button, it is being re-created from scratch. Difference is that savedInstanceState != null. I readed android docs. I need to emulate this behviour, because I think that some data is not restored propertly.